Zoom Meeting Web SDK: Unable to Capture Audio Using Virtual Audio Cable (VAC) as Default Speaker/Output Device
I'm working on a project where I need to capture audio from a Zoom meeting using the Zoom Meeting Web SDK. The goal is to process the audio through a Virtual Audio Cable (VAC) output and store it in a file.
The problem:
When I use my system's default output (e.g., built-in), I am able to capture the audio from the Zoom meeting without any issues. However, when I set VAC as my default speakers, no audio is captured during the meeting.
My setup:

I'm using Zoom Meeting Web SDK to join Zoom meetings in a browser.
I have configured Virtual Audio Cable (VAC) as the default output in my system.
When I switch back to my system device, the audio is captured successfully.

I have tried:

Verified that VAC is set as the default input/output device in the system's audio settings.
Also is the same process possible with puppeteer fake media stream.

Client-side
 navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
    })
    .then((stream) => {
      console.log("Audio stream obtained:", stream);

      const audioContext = new window.AudioContext();
      const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      const chunks = [];

      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
        chunks.push(event.data);
      };

      mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
        const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/webm" });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        // Automatically download the recorded audio
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.style.display = "none";
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "recorded-audio.webm";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();

        setTimeout(() => {
          document.body.removeChild(a);
          URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }, 1000);
      };

      // Start recording for 20 seconds
      mediaRecorder.start();
      setTimeout(() => {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
      }, 20000);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Error accessing media devices:", err);
    });

Server-side

    export const clickJoinMeetingButton = async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await launch(puppeteer, {
      headless: false,
      args: [
        "--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required",
        "--disable-web-security",
        "--allow-file-access",
        "--disable-notifications",
        "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream",
        "--no-default-browser-check",
        // "--use-fake-device-for-media-stream",
      ],
      ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--mute-audio"],
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(process.env.FRONTEND_URL || "", {
      waitUntil: "load",
    });

    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);

    const button = await page.waitForSelector('button[id="join_meeting"]', {
      visible: true,
      timeout: 10000,
    });
    if (button) {
      await button.evaluate((node) => {
        if (node && node.click) {
          node.click();
        }
      });
      console.log("Join Button Clicked Successfully");
    } else {
      console.log("Join Button not found or not clickable");
    }

    await page.waitForSelector(".footer__leave-btn", { visible: true });
    console.log("The leave button is visible.");

  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
};


How can I configure Zoom Meeting Web SDK and VAC so that the audio from the Zoom meeting can be captured when VAC is set as the default device? Is there any additional configuration or workaround needed to make VAC work with Zoom?
Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

@ggorlen I am using Puppeteer for launching a browser and joining a Zoom meeting. After the meeting is joined, I handle capturing the audio stream client-side using the Zoom Web SDK. The code provided above for getting the audio stream runs within the client’s context (the browser instance controlled by Puppeteer).
